# Webpage change in jsp and backe end Struts 1.x version

Tags: java, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, compatibility, struts-1

Am new to bootstrap and I want to know 
if bootstrap supports struts1.x version , 
as I need it in my current project ?

I tried calling the form action in jsp , but the page is not fetching.

```
    <form class="form-signin" action='/Login' method="GET">
        some code
```

Please help if any one knows bootstrap is supported in struts1.x?

Comment: Your question is not clear, you need to put more explanation and background to it.

Comment: i need to know if bootstrap supports struts1.x version .